# Didn't choose default option while installing KDE in arch linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, kde-plasma

As I wanted to learn Linux better, after using Fedora for a while I installed Arch Linux. Install was ok and working fine. But while I was installing KDE desktop environment, I didn't choose default(all) option, rather I choose randomnly a number for every step. KDE got installed and working. However I didn't used KDE before. I'm suspecting everything didn't installed. Did I made mistake choosing a random option instead choosing default? Can I install those packages for KDE?

Comment: Choosing randomly can NOT be a mistake, never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to choose **"all"** from the group *[plasma](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/plasma/)* under *[Pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman)* to have a full working desktop environment.

**But, not choosing "all" is not a mistake at all.**

You can at any time install the package you want *one by one* with:

```
pacman -S nameOfPackage
```

or install **all** non-installed packages from *[plasma](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/plasma/)* with:

```
pacman -S plasma
```